# Populate bootstrap table with JQuery and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to populate my bootstrap table (in Database.Master) with  data (in DatabaseUI.aspx.cs).

How do I dynamically add rows to the table with Jquery?

Do I have to convert my string to JSON?
I think I have to add another JQuery script in the masterpagefile to append data to the table

```
$(function() {
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
    var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.UID)
    .appendTo('#lblDatabase');
});});
```

but I'm not sure how to pass to get *response* in the script to read the string in DatabaseUI.

In Database.Master

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <table class="table" id="lblDatabase">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Pid</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDatabaseValues" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

Code that gets data from API in DatabaseUI

```
 protected async void GetRequest(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    Label lblDatabaseValues = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblDatabaseValues");
                    //lblDatabaseValues.Text = "Values:";
                    //lblDatabaseValues.Text = "";
                    string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    string[] values = myContent.Split(';');
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                    {
                        lblDatabaseValues.Text = lblDatabaseValues.Text + Environment.NewLine + values[i];
                    }
                    lblDatabaseValues.Text = lblDatabaseValues.Text.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
                }
                //response.IsSuccessStatusCode
                //response.StatusCode
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the question is not much clear. If you are asking about how to loop over the received response from backend and append it to your table then here is the code for you.

```
<table id="tdUIDs">
</table>

var rows = "";
$.each(response,function(i,item){
rows += "<tr><td>" + item.UID + "</td></tr>"; //your rows get printed here
});

$("#tdUIDs").append(rows);
```

I hope this is what you are asking for as am not clear with your question.